# What is a concise way of saying "Tracking the flow of statement execution within this method"

Tags: python

I'm sorry if I'm not asking this correctly.  It may be due to a lack of understanding.

If I was explaining to someone how to understand of a piece of code that's been written by someone else..I would say something like:

"Ok so here we have this method getting called and it's taking one argument.  Let's find the method declaration itself and see what it's doing and what it's doing to our argument."

Is there a concise way of describing looking at code backwards in a way?  Following the sequence of events?  Flow of execution?  Flow/order of operations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My professors refer to it as *tracing* a function. It might be linked to localisation (I'm in France and translating their word into English) or to a specific language, but that's what I got and it sounds right.

I think [this bit of Python doc](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/thinkcspy/Functions/FlowofExecutionSummary.html) supports my proposed answer.

Comment: Nice.  I love it!